# Is it possible to grab the user's message from the IDialogContext parameter?

Tags: c#, botframework

In one of the examples on the Microsoft Bot Framework page, they have the following code:

```
[Serializable]
public class EchoDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        await context.PostAsync("You said: " + message.Text);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}

    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        // check if activity is of type message
        if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

Is it possible to grab the user's message that is passed from Post to the StartAsync method via the context parameter? Is it also possible to store things in it? The documentation is going way over my head and I'd just like to know if this thing is modifiable at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constructor to EchoDialog that stores whatever data you like e.g. the Activity instance.